# Enums in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I want to create a enum in Elixir. Is it possible? By enum I mean enums from C/C++ or Ruby or in many other languages. I'm aware of the `Enum` module but that's just a module -- a container for functions basically.

Comment: What you probably need is a [list](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/basic-types.html#linked-lists) along with the [Enum module](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/enumerables-and-streams.html#enumerables). Elixir like Erlang is a functional programming language with immutable data types so you start with a list, apply transformations (via the Enum or Stream module ) and then you can use the output however you decide.

Comment: What do you mean by enums in Ruby? There's Enumerable and Enumerator in Ruby which are completely different from an `enum` in C or C++.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for a way to use enumeration in Elixir. You can do this with an instance of a Map using :atoms as keys.

```
 weekdays = [:monday, :tuesday, :wednesday, :thursday, :friday, :saturday, :sunday]
    |> Enum.with_index 
    |> Map.new
```

Or a bit more manually

```
weekdays = %{
    monday: 0,
    tuesday: 1,
    wednesday: 2,
    thursday: 3,
    friday: 4,
    saturday: 5,
    sunday: 6}
```

If you're using :atoms as keys, the short-hand access syntax is:

```
iex> weekdays.monday
0
iex> weekdays.friday
4
```

But usually using atoms such as :error or :ok doesn't require you to do these declarations.

Answer (score 15):

You could just use atoms. For static analysis, you can define a type that accepts only certain values and use that in your typespecs. You can then check your code with [dialyxir](https://github.com/jeremyjh/dialyxir) for example.

```
@type state :: :a | :b | :c

@spec set_state(pid, state) :: :ok | {:error, term}
def set_state(pid, state)
  # ...
end

@spec get_state(pid) :: state
def get_state(pid)
  # ...
end
```

Comment: that's a library, I don't want to use a library.

Comment: It's just a development tool though, you don't need it at runtime and it will leave no traces in compiled code.

Comment: The type thing is just what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

I think the short answer is No. If by enum, you mean a static user defined
type enforced at compile time, (i.e. c enums), then the answer is definitely no.

The long answer is that there are only a fixed number of basic data types in the underlying VM of Elixir/Erlang. There are the basic data types:

```
[Atom, Integer, Float, BitString, Regexp, PID, Function, Reference, Port]
```

and the 3 Container types.

```
[Tuple, List, Map]
```

You can compose these types to create very complex data structures, but if you want to apply "rules" to the behaviour of those composed types, you need to create a library or module of functions for manipulating those types according to the rules.

Since Elixir is a dynamic language, it's is always possible to "reach" into any complex data type and completely transform it. There's no way to enforce rules on values unless you do that through a set of defined functions. My guess is that what you're looking for is a `FixedSet` type than can only take values from a pre-defined list of values. That would be relatively straightforward to implement as a module, but writing a module of functions( and likely some macros) is the only way to accomplish that kind of functionality in Elixir.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if it is a good idea, but you can create a module (CustomEnum) where  you define functions as Enums.

```
defmodule CustomEnum do
  def monday, do: 0
  def tuesday,do: 1
end
```

Then, you can call **CustomEnum.monday** and get value **0**

Write all this functions could be boring, so you can create a list of tuples and dynamically create your function for each item.
EX>

```
defmodule CustomWeekDaysEnum do
  weekdays = [ 
    monday: {0},
    tuesday: {1},
    wednesday: {2},
    thursday: {3}
    ....
  ]

  #creating functions dynamically
  for{function_name, {value} <- weekdays do
    def unquote(function_name)(), do: unquote(value)
  end
end
```

Now you call **CustomWeekDaysEnum.wednesday** and get 2, or **CustomWeekDaysEnum.thursday** and get 3.

And now, if you need a new Enum item, just put it in **weekdays** List and your  function will be created at compile time.

**weekdays** is a list  of tuples, so your enums can have multiple values inside. you just have to change **unquoted def** to return the tuple or just specific values

Just remember:
Functions dynamically created are cool but your code may become harder to read.

You can find more about it in Saša Jurić post

[The Erlangelist](https://www.theerlangelist.com/article/macros_1)

Comment: I think this is the way enums are supposed to be managed bottom line in Elixir.. every library does pretty much something like this.. 
I've been using enum_type so far, but the problem there is that for each enum value it generates a beam file hence for protocols with lots of enums this is going to explode and consume a lot of ram and takes time for the application to bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

You could use for example this library: [jcomellas/ex_const](https://github.com/jcomellas/ex_const). It allows you to define enums like this:

```
enum <name> do
  <key_1> <value_1>
  <key_2> <value_2>
  [...]
end
```

**Sample code** (taken from documentation on GitHub):

Definition:

```
enum country_code do
  argentina "AR"
  italy     "IT"
  usa       "US"
end
```

Usage:

```
require Settings
import Settings
value = "AR"
case value do
  country_code(:argentina) ->
    {:ok, "Argentina"}
  country_code(:italy) ->
    {:ok, "Italy"}
  code when code == country_code(:usa) ->
    {:ok, "United States"}
  _ ->
    {:error, {:must_be_one_of, country_codes()}}
end
```